# Locate and add favorite apps Linux Mint 20 via CLI

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, gnome, gnome-shell

I know, that you can add applications with right click -> Add to favorites.

But I want to add / remove the favorites via script.

I was trying to use the solution from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193496/add-app-to-favorites-from-command-line) but

When executing following command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps
```

I receive following error:

No such schema »org.gnome.shell«

When searching all gsettings for 'favorite' there wasn't anything that fits.

The only thing is `com.linuxmint.mintmenu.plugins.applications` but that's empty. (My favorites are definetely not empty)

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep 'favorite'

com.linuxmint.mintmenu applet-icons ['linuxmint-logo', 'linuxmint-logo-badge', 'linuxmint-logo-badge-symbolic', 'linuxmint-logo-filled-badge', 'linuxmint-logo-filled-leaf-badge', 'linuxmint-logo-filled-leaf', 'linuxmint-logo-filled-ring', 'linuxmint-logo-leaf-badge', 'linuxmint-logo-leaf-badge-symbolic', 'linuxmint-logo-leaf', 'linuxmint-logo-leaf-symbolic', 'linuxmint-logo-neon', 'linuxmint-logo-ring', 'linuxmint-logo-ring-symbolic', 'linuxmint-logo-simple', 'linuxmint-logo-simple-symbolic', 'mate-symbolic', 'emblem-favorite-symbolic', 'user-bookmarks-symbolic', 'start-here-symbolic']
com.linuxmint.mintmenu start-with-favorites false
org.x.warpinator.preferences favorites @as []
com.linuxmint.mintmenu.plugins.applications favorite-apps-list @as []
```

I couldn't find a solution where my favorites are saved or can be changed.

Does anyone know a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on my own. The solution was quiet simple..

I executed the command as root, that's the reason why the `favorite-apps-list` was empty, after executing as my user everything worked as expected.